# Design Pattern Singleton implemented in JavaScript Code error

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have the CalculationDesignSingleton.js file, and the CalculationDesignSingleton.test.js which is using Jest to test the file. When I run the test file, I received an error said calculation.getInstance is not a function. Can someone help me? Thank you

CalculationDesignSingleton.js

```
let calculation = (function () {
let instance;
function createInstance() {
    let calculator = new Calculator("I am the instance");
    return calculator;
}

return {
    getInstance: function () {
        if (!instance) {
            instance = createInstance();
        }
        return instance;
    }
};
})();
```

CalculationDesignSingleton.test.js

```
const calculation = require('../src/Operations/CalculationDesignSingleton');

test('Test Design Pattern Singleton of Calculation', () => {
    //I need to test the get results function
    const singletonA = calculation.getInstance();
    const singletonB = calculation.getInstance();
    const isEqual = singletonA === singletonB;
    expect(isEqual).toBe(true);
});
```

Comment: `const singletonA = calculation.getInstance()`

Comment: And FWIW, IIFE is obsolete in modular environment.